# Create a SSL authentication on gRPC server using Nest.js

Tags: node.js, nestjs, grpc

I'm trying to implement a gRPC server with SSL authentication using Nest.js following the documentation but it throws a compilation throws an error.

When I try to follow the [official docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/grpc) to set the server credentials like this:

```js
{
  transport: Transport.GRPC,
  options: {
    url: `0.0.0.0:9090`,
    package: ['myProto'],
    protoPath: ['protoPath/myProto.proto'],
    credentials: grpc.ServerCredentials.createSsl(
      null,
      [
        {
          cert_chain: certChain,
          private_key: privateKey,
        },
      ],
    ),
  },
}
```

It just throws
`TypeError: Channel credentials must be a ChannelCredentials object`.

I tried to ignore the docs and set a ChannelCredentials:

```js
{
  transport: Transport.GRPC,
  options: {
    url: `0.0.0.0:9090`,
    package: ['myProto'],
    protoPath: ['protoPath/myProto.proto'],
    credentials: grpc.ChannelCredentials.createSsl(
      rootCert,
      privateKey,
      certChain,
    ),
  },
}
```

But then it throws `TypeError: creds must be a ServerCredentials object`.

The Nest interface specifies `credentials` as `any`, so it doesn't help so much.

Comment: Please move the *answer* to an *answer*, remote it from you *question*, remove the unnecessary `SOLVED` from the title and, after sufficient time has elapsed, *accept* your own answer. I.e. please learn how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem just not following the example provided by the documentation.

The Documentation example uses:

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(grpcClientOptions);

await app.startAllMicroservices();
await app.listen(3001);
```

Which throws the error indicated previously. Instead, I used ServerCredentials on my grpcClientOptions and then:

```
const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(
  AppModule,
  grpcClientOptions,
);
app.listen();
```

Just with this little change everything works as intended, even the server reflection.